# How to unit test IDataErrorInfo?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, idataerrorinfo

I am reading Asp.net MVC Framework and I am reading about IDataErrorInfo as form of validation.

So I am just going to post what he has.

Product Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    public partial class Product : IDataErrorInfo
    {

        private Dictionary<string, string> _errors = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        partial void OnNameChanging(string value)
        {
            if (value.Trim() == String.Empty)
                _errors.Add("Name", "Name is required.");
        }


        partial void OnPriceChanging(decimal value)
        {
            if (value <= 0m)
                _errors.Add("Price", "Price must be greater than 0.");
        }


        #region IDataErrorInfo Members

        public string Error
        {
            get { return string.Empty; }
        }

        public string this[string columnName]
        {
            get
            {
                if (_errors.ContainsKey(columnName))
                    return _errors[columnName];
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }

        #endregion


    }
}
```

ProductRepository.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    public class ProductRepository : IProductRepository
    {
        private ProductsDBEntities _entities = new ProductsDBEntities();

        public IEnumerable<Product> ListProducts()
        {
            return _entities.ProductSet.ToList();
        }

        public void CreateProduct(Product productToCreate)
        {
            _entities.AddToProductSet(productToCreate);
            _entities.SaveChanges();
        }

    }

    public interface IProductRepository
    {
        IEnumerable<Product> ListProducts();
        void CreateProduct(Product productToCreate);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MvcApplication1.Models;

namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        private IProductRepository _repository; 

        public ProductController()
            :this(new ProductRepository()){}


        public ProductController(IProductRepository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }


        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(_repository.ListProducts());
        }


        //
        // GET: /Product/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        } 

        //
        // POST: /Product/Create

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude="Id")]Product productToCreate)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return View();
            _repository.CreateProduct(productToCreate);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }


    }
}
```

Yet No where in the book do I see how to actually unit test this. Like he shows you how to unit test his service layer stuff but nothing about unit testing IDataErrorInfo.

So how would I unit test this? I like checking the error messages to see if they are the same. Like if I pass in a null field I like to check if the error message would be the right one for this null field.

After I like to check if statement logic after the stuff that needs to be validated to see if it is doing what is expected but I don't even know how to call this partial class up especially since you normally don't want to hit the database when doing unit tests.

Comment: The Product class you posted is partial. There must be one or more additional implementations of the Product class that (among other things) invoke the partial methdods. It's not very easy to answer your question when we don't know what that looks like. Additionally, I fail to see how the Repository and Controller has anything to do with this, so maybe you could trim down your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unit testing IDataErrorInfo is quite easy. Just set up your tests with a "valid" instance of the object, then test that you can make it error:

```
[TestFixture]
public class ErrorTests
{
    private Product _product; // subject under test

    [SetUp]
    public void Create_valid_instance()
    {
        _product = new Product { /* valid values */ };
    }

    [Test]
    public void Name_cannot_be_null()
    {
        _product.Name = null; 
        Assert.AreEqual("Name is required.", _product.Error);
        Assert.AreEqual("Name is required.", _product["Name"]);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Name_cannot_be_empty()
    {
        _product.Name = String.Empty; 
        Assert.AreEqual("Name is required.", _product.Error);
        Assert.AreEqual("Name is required.", _product["Name"]);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Name_cannot_be_whitespace()
    {
        _product.Name = "   ";
        Assert.AreEqual("Name is required.", _product.Error);
        Assert.AreEqual("Name is required.", _product["Name"]);
    }

    /* etc - add tests to prove that errors can occur */
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to be true.  The error indexer (this[]) only appears to be called in my app when I turn on ValidatseOnDataErrors in my xaml.  In my test app, which seems to lack a place to turn that on, the error indexer is never checked on my IDataErrorInfo business objects. So setting myObject.Name = string.Empty; will never check the name rule.  I'm still looking for a way to do this.

Comment: So, just so we're clear: I post some tests, and because you can't make them pass, you give me downvotes? Return the error from your Error property as well as the indexer! Then the tests pass!

Answer (score 3):

The solution mentioned by Matt only works for me if i use the later statement to Assert -

Assert.AreEqual("Name is required.", _product["Name"]); - this works for me

Assert.AreEqual("Name is required.", _product.Error); - this doesn't work for me